# How can I detect if my browser is Firefox?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC3 and I would like to set just one single CSS value differently if I am using Firefox. This concerns the paddings on buttons which seems to not be the same across all browsers.

How can I detect if my browser is Firefox.

Hope someone knows the answer.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I needed myself a browser detection script, so I found this js script [browserDetect.js](http://pastebin.com/4D71sDZc) (Sorry, I didn't find the official project site)

This script let's you manipulate CSS very easily.
So if for example you have like:

```
#my-id
{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And in Firefox 4, for instance you want another setting for `#my-id`, you can do something like this:

```
.browserFirefox4 #my-id
{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And it detects the majority of the browsers.